# RoboSharp Example Windows .Net

Tags: c#, robocopy

.Net 5 Console App

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string _source = @"c:\temptemp";

        string __destination = @"c:\temp1";

        CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance.GetEncoding(437);
        Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

        RoboCommand copyCommand = new RoboCommand();
        copyCommand.CopyOptions.Source = _source;
        copyCommand.CopyOptions.Destination = __destination;
        copyCommand.CopyOptions.Mirror = true;

        copyCommand.OnCommandCompleted += CopyCommand_OnCommandCompleted;
        copyCommand.Start().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        var running = copyCommand.IsRunning;


        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void CopyCommand_OnCommandCompleted(RoboSharp.Interfaces.IRoboCommand sender, RoboCommandCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

I am using the Nuget Robosharp package v1.2.8

This does not seem to work. I would expect the copy to happen and the completed event to trigger but it doesn't. I am using mirror so the copy of the source should go to the destination.

Ideas?

Comment: .NET 5 is no longer supported. See [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core#lifecycle) for more info. Unfortunately, .NET6 doesn't show up as an option in VS 2019. In order to use .NET 6, you'll need [VS 2022](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/).

Comment: That doesn't mean it suddenly stops working.